# Cannot read properties of null but the variable is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, react-fullstack

I'm trying to implement my first full stack project according to the next YouTube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Y5QKfxTErU

Based on MERN technology.

Implementing that step by step.

Until some part Everything just going as on video, until React part at 1:32:22
when Author got working page of http://localhost:3000/books
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azeEm.jpg)
when I'm getting the next Error Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axl0m.p**ng)

**Edited: Second image is incorrect ,the actual error is:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

While playing with code lines if found out that the next line cause the error in Books.js
 `<Book  book={book}  />`

The same error jumps 5 times as a number of Book's properties (not including _id)
I feel lost a little bit, because I'm doing the same code, maybe somebody could help with debug that or avoid the cause of getting the null pointer?
Thanks in advance.
Here are the pieces of code on client side:

Books.js:

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';  
import Book from './Book';
const URL = "http://localhost:5000/books"; 
const fetchHandler = async()=>{
    return await axios.get(URL).then((res)=>res.data);
};  
const Books = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState();
    useEffect(()=>{
fetchHandler().then((data)=>setBooks(data.books));
  },[]);
  console.log(books);
return (
    <div>
    <ul>
    {books && books.map((book,i)=>(
      <div  key={i}>
      <Book  book={book}  />
      </div>
    ))}
  </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Books
```

Book.js

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React from 'react'

const Book = (props) => {
    const {_id,name,author,description,price,image} = props.book;
  return (
    <div>
     <img src={image} alt={name} />
     <article>By {author}</article> 
     <h3>{name}</h3>
     <p>{description}</p>
     <h2>Rs {price}</h2>
     <Button>Update</Button>
     <Button>Delete</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Book


./backend/controllers/books-controller.js

    const Book = require("../model/Book"); 
const booksController = require("../controllers/books-controller");

// router.get("/",booksController.getAllBooks)
const getAllBooks = async(req,res,next) =>{
        //This route will provide all of the books
        let books;
        try {
            books=await Book.find();
        }catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    
        if(!books){
            return res.status(404).json({message:"No products found"})
        }
        return res.status(200).json({books:books});
}

const addBook = async(req,res,next)=>{
    let book;
    try{
        const {name,author,description,price,available,image}=req.body;
        book = new Book ({
            name,author,description,price,available,image
        });
        await book.save();
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    if (!book){
        return res.status(500).json({message:'Unable to add book'})
    }
    return res.status(201).json({book});
};

const getById = async(req,res,next)=>{
    const id = req.params.id
    let book;
    try{
        book = await Book.findById(id);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    if(!book){
        return res.status(404).json({message:"No book found"})
    }
    return res.status(200).json({book});

};

const updateBook = async(req,res,next)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    const {name,author,description,price,available,image}=req.body;
    let book;
    try{
        book = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
            name,
            author,
            description,
            price,
            available,
            image
        });
        book = await book.save();
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    if(!book){
        return res.status(404).json({message:"Unable to update book"})
    }
    return res.status(200).json({book});
}

const deleteBook = async (req,res,next)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;
    let book;
    try{
        book = await Book.findByIdAndRemove(id);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    if(!book){
        return res.status(404).json({message:"Unable to remove book"})
    }
    return res.status(200).json({message:"Book successfully deleted"});
}
exports.getAllBooks = getAllBooks;
exports.addBook = addBook;
exports.getById = getById;
exports.updateBook = updateBook;
exports.deleteBook = deleteBook;

./backend/model/Book.js

const mongoose = require ('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bookSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },
    available: {
        type:Boolean,
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book",bookSchema);

./backend/routes/book-routes.js  
const express = require ("express");
const router = express.Router(); 
const Book = require("../model/Book");
const booksController = require("../controllers/books-controller");
router.get ("/", booksController.getAllBooks);
router.post("/",booksController.addBook);
router.get("/:id",booksController.getById);
router.put("/:id",booksController.updateBook);
router.delete("/:id",booksController.deleteBook);
module.exports = router;

./backend/app.js:
// console.log("Hello world!");
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = require("./routes/book-routes");
const app = express();
const cors = require ('cors');
//Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/books",router)//localhost:5000/books
// app.use('/',(req,res,next)=>{
//     res.send ("This is our starting app");
// }) USELESS

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.xvssizl.mongodb.net/bookStore?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
.then(()=>console.log("Connected to Database"))
    .then(()=>{
        app.listen(5000);
    }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are different things in JavaScript. A variable can be defined as `null`, so for some reason you are getting that value from the backend.

Comment: maybe you know something about troubles with axious or cors modules?

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(books)`?

Answer (score -2):

Here are some problems that I see in your code:

1. Default State of books: The default state of books is undefined as you've declared it like this: const [books, setBooks] = useState();. This means, before the data is fetched from your server, books will be undefined. Your check {books && books.map(...) will prevent errors if books is undefined or null, but we should also ensure that the data you're getting from the server is actually in the shape you expect.
2. Shape of Server Response: Make sure that the data you get from the server (http://localhost:5000/books) is indeed an object with a books key, and that key contains an array of book objects. A common mistake is that the server might just send an array directly, in which case you'd just do setBooks(data) instead of setBooks(data.books).
3. Error Handling: There isn't any error handling in your fetching function. It's possible that the axios request fails for some reason (server not running, wrong endpoint, etc.), and in such cases, it's good to have an error handler to understand what's going wrong.
4. Data Structure in Book Component: Ensure that every book object passed to the Book component has all the required properties: _id, name, author, description, price, image. If any of these are missing or are null, then trying to destructure them will throw an error.

Here an optimized version of the components:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Book from './Book';

const URL = "http://localhost:5000/books";

const Books = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBooks = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(URL);
        setBooks(response.data.books || []);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
      }
    };

    fetchBooks();
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error loading books: {error}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {books && books.map((book, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <Book {...book} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Books;
```

and:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Book = ({ _id, name, author, description, price, image }) => {
  if (!_id || !name || !author || !description || !price || !image) {
    console.error("Missing book properties:", { _id, name, author, description, price, image });
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={image} alt={name} />
      <article>By {author}</article>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <p>{description}</p>
      <h2>Rs {price}</h2>
      <Button>Update</Button>
      <Button>Delete</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

Book.propTypes = {
  _id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  author: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  image: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Book;
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but i still get the same error, maybe the trouble is on the server side?

Comment: I just noticed that we both have an error on server url: the correct is "http://localhost:3000/books"

Comment: No, 5000 is a server port, 3000 is a client port